# Upgraded to angular 6 and jQuery stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, webpack

I just upgraded from `Angular 5.2.5` to `Angular 6.0.1` and `Webpack 4.8.3`. However when I try to load pages that use Jquery I get `$(...).func is not a function` in my console.

I import jquery in my entire app through my webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: "jquery",
        $: "jquery",
        jquery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
],
```

So far I haven't found anything that changed about this, and even in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery) it looks the same, yet it's not working since the upgrade.

Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery with Angular. That's bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried expose loader?

There's a sample of how to add jQuery in:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

I use it myself like so in vendor.ts:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var $: any;

import 'expose-loader?$!expose-loader?window.jQuery!jquery';

(<any>window).jQuery = $;
```

Comment: This needs to either contain more details or be a comment